# Check programmatically [reg entry] if java script is enabled for chrome/firefox and other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, inno-setup

I would like to check programmatically if java script is enabled for any browser, For IE I could use the below registry entry, but I am not able to find for chrome or other browsers. Please help.

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings\Zones\3 
subkey: 1400  
Value 0 [enabled], 3 [Disabled]
```

I am creating a inno setup and want to use the code in it.

Comment: I don't know what "inno" is but do you need an operating system setting to do this or can it be "in browser"?

Comment: For Chrome you can check if the value of [`DefaultJavaScriptSetting`](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultJavaScriptSetting) is 1 and if not, check if the URL of your choice is black-listed or white-listed in `JavaScriptAllowedForUrls` or `JavaScriptBlockedForUrls` setting.

Comment: @Rob, i would need operting system setting, like i should be able to check in a registry, as i need to write it in a scripting language

Comment: @TLama that setting is for chromium, I have chrome installed on my machine and i dont see that reg entry.

Comment: Neither me, but see the very first note on top of that page *Both Chromium and Google Chrome support the same set of policies*.

Comment: Yes, its mentioned, but unfortunately not available for chrome.

Comment: Hm, it seems that Chrome stores the preferences in one of its JSON files (but hard to say which one as it seems they are related to the user which is logged on to the Google account). Still, this becomes far more complicated since if the settings I've linked in my comment also affects the Chrome policy settings, which one has higher priority then ? Those JSON file settings or what's in the registry ? This is very broad to answer unless Google publishes this info, not speaking about the need of having JSON parser for Inno Setup. And we are at the first browser...